# How to call a webservice from android

Tags: java, android

I have a webAPI that i need to call from java sever side code and get the response coming from the service ..
Here is my webAPI URL..

```
http://pnrbuddy.com/api/check_pnr/pnr/2156641988/format/json/pbapikey/6b17f33e25e2d8197462d1c6bcb0b130/pbapisign/bd0aea241e88c8a22692eba02887ad97a220f827
```

This is a responsive URL ..You can check the values on typing on the Browser URL.The response of the datatype can be either xml or json.

How do I call this webAPI from android?

Comment: *I have a webAPI that i need to call from java sever side code* -- did you mean from the Android client side code?

Comment: What is your problem exactly? To execute HTTP requests from android, you can take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-an-http-request-with-android

Comment: @Joffrey I have a button in my android app and on button click i want to call that WebAPI...

Comment: @Joffrey That URL is responsive u can type that in Browser and see the response

Comment: And what would I do with the response? I'm asking about your question. What is it you don't manage to do? Executing an HTTP request? Reading the result? Also, you have a '…' character in your URL, I'm not sure the "HMAC SIGNATURE MISMATCH" I get is the right response...

Comment: @Joffrey Sorry sir..How can i call this URL from android button click event ..This is my question.I am sorry for last time ..

Comment: To "call an URL", you have to send an HTTP request. To see how to do it, follow the link I provided in my second comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-an-http-request-with-android

Comment: @Joffrey I updated the post to correct the API URL ,please see it..If you please provide me a hint with pseudo code in my case,it would be very helpfull for me,i am novice developer who is trying to grasp the things..

Comment: i don't understand the question. I don't actually see a question.

Comment: @Siddhu, you seem to have included your API keys in your question. I suggest you change the keys and/or remove the question to protect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This forum is here to help with specific programming problems, but people usually won't write a big chunk of business code for you.

However, we can give you hints:

- to "call a Webservice API", you'll need to execute some HTTP requests.
  You can find how to do so [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-an-http-request-with-android), using Android's [HttpClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html).
- your server's response is in the [JSON format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).
  Once you get a `String` out of your response, you can use the [org.json API](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) to parse it.

Comment: Downvoter, would you please care to comment? This way I could improve my answer if something is incorrect or missing.

Comment: It wasn't me that downvoted but there are some people on Meta that believe that answering bad questions is bad for the site. I'm not one of them though.

Comment: @CurlyPaul OK, I understand. Well it's not as if I provided a full answer to a too broad question, I merely give directions for the OP to keep on searching.

Comment: I would agree, being helpful to new members is the right way tp go imo as well

Answer (score 0):

My favorite way of doing it is using a helper library called RestTemplate. You can find a guide on how to do it in under 15 minutes here: http://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-android/.

It even shows you how to make a model that represents your json and have jackson deserialize your json into a java object for you.